# Offline message show as ???? , aSmack and openfire

Tags: offline, openfire

I use asmack and openfire for chat application and have two problem:

1. Problem with offline message encoding :

   - user A send message to user B(is offline)
   - B can received offline message but when user A use Persian character user B see message like '????'.
2. How to detect message was sent?

I use below code to set message as sent.
below code work when I have good Internet access but some time when use poor internet access, message set as sent but doesn't sent really.

```java
try {
    connection.sendPacket(msg);
    db.setMessageState(id, MessageModel.STATE_SENT);
} catch (Exception e) {
    db.setMessageState(id, MessageModel.STATE_ERROR);
}
```

**Edit:**

My first problem was solved, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25358854/1391249) link may be helpful.

Comment: i'm not familiar with open fire, but it will be good if you check is it really decoding problem or display

Comment: I use same way  to display  offline/online message and don't have problem with online message(user B is online) and have encoding problem when see archive message from server panel,thank

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in the same post.

Answer (score -1):

```
configureConnection(ProviderManager.getInstance());
             OfflineMessageManager offlineManager = new OfflineMessageManager( 
               connection);
             int count = offlineManager.getMessageCount();
                    Iterator<Message> it = offlineManager.getMessages();
                        while (it.hasNext()) {
                                Message m = it.next();
                                String fromName = m.getFrom();
                                //Date currentDate = new Date();
                                String text = m.getBody() + " (offline)";
                                if(fromName.contains("/Smack")){
                                    fromName = fromName.replace("/Smack","");
                                }
                                Log.i("offile chat message with user name ",text+" username "+fromName);
                                dbHelper.addmessageUser(fromName, text, "0", "1",""+System.currentTimeMillis());
                                if(offlineMsgs.containsKey(fromName))    
                                {    
                                    offlineMsgs.get(fromName).add(m);    
                                }else{    
                                    ArrayList<Message> temp = new ArrayList<Message>();    
                                    temp.add(m);    
                                    offlineMsgs.put(fromName, temp);    
                                } 
                                // ...
                        }


                        offlineManager.deleteMessages();



    // 
 public void configureConnection(ProviderManager pm) {


         // Private Data Storage
            pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:private", new PrivateDataManager.PrivateDataIQProvider());
            // Time
            try
            {
                pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:time", Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time"));
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
            {
                Log.w("TestClient", "Can't load class for org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Time");
            }
            // Roster Exchange
            pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:roster", new RosterExchangeProvider());
            // Message Events
            pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:event", new MessageEventProvider());
            // Chat State
            pm.addExtensionProvider("active", "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
            pm.addExtensionProvider("composing", "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
            pm.addExtensionProvider("paused", "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
            pm.addExtensionProvider("inactive", "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
            pm.addExtensionProvider("gone", "http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates", new ChatStateExtension.Provider());
            // XHTML
            pm.addExtensionProvider("html", "http://jabber.org/protocol/xhtml-im", new XHTMLExtensionProvider());
            // Group Chat Invitations
            pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:conference", new GroupChatInvitation.Provider());
            // Service Discovery # Items
            pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items", new DiscoverItemsProvider());
            // Service Discovery # Info
            pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info", new DiscoverInfoProvider());
            // Data Forms
            pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:data", new DataFormProvider());
            // MUC User
            pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user", new MUCUserProvider());
            // MUC Admin
            pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin", new MUCAdminProvider());
            // MUC Owner
            pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#owner", new MUCOwnerProvider());
            // Delayed Delivery
            pm.addExtensionProvider("x", "jabber:x:delay", new DelayInformationProvider());
            // Version
            try
            {
                pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:version", Class.forName("org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.Version"));
            }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
            {
                // Not sure what's happening here.
            }
            // VCard
            pm.addIQProvider("vCard", "vcard-temp", new VCardProvider());
            // Offline Message Requests
            pm.addIQProvider("offline", "http://jabber.org/protocol/offline", new OfflineMessageRequest.Provider());
            // Offline Message Indicator
            pm.addExtensionProvider("offline", "http://jabber.org/protocol/offline", new OfflineMessageInfo.Provider());
            // Last Activity
            pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:last", new LastActivity.Provider());
            // User Search
            pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:search", new UserSearch.Provider());
            // SharedGroupsInfo
            pm.addIQProvider("sharedgroup", "http://www.jivesoftware.org/protocol/sharedgroup", new SharedGroupsInfo.Provider());
            // JEP-33: Extended Stanza Addressing
            pm.addExtensionProvider("addresses", "http://jabber.org/protocol/address", new MultipleAddressesProvider());
            // FileTransfer
            pm.addIQProvider("si", "http://jabber.org/protocol/si", new StreamInitiationProvider());
            pm.addIQProvider("query", "http://jabber.org/protocol/bytestreams", new BytestreamsProvider());
            // Privacy
            pm.addIQProvider("query", "jabber:iq:privacy", new PrivacyProvider());
            pm.addIQProvider("command", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider());
            pm.addExtensionProvider("malformed-action", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider.MalformedActionError());
            pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-locale", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadLocaleError());
            pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-payload", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadPayloadError());
            pm.addExtensionProvider("bad-sessionid", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider.BadSessionIDError());
            pm.addExtensionProvider("session-expired", "http://jabber.org/protocol/commands", new AdHocCommandDataProvider.SessionExpiredError());
        }
```