# Offline Emoticons/Smileys showing ???? in MySql ofOffline table

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am working on an chat application which send emoticons over the network and uses openfire as Xmpp Server.

I am facing an issue while sending emoticons in the Message Stanza while the recipient is in offline state. The Message is inserted into the ofOffline Table(based on MySql) by converting the Smiley's to ??????.

This is the ofOffline log:

```
<message to="1896127963944789@xxx" id="lQ7TP-99" type="chat" from="803084821356919@xxx/Smack"><body>{"message":"????????????","timestamp":1451299511711,"senderName":"john"}</body><thread>e5835bf7-e505-43e5-81cf-0e32e636afa8</thread></message>
```

I have tried the following Solutions:

1) https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#utf8-to-utf8mb4

i.e  `by changing the Charset from utf8 toutf8mb4.(Followed each step but no success)`

2) Changed the conf/openfire.xml as per the link.

[Openfire: Offline UTF-8 encoded messages are saved wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358854/openfire-offline-utf-8-encoded-messages-are-saved-wrong)

But no success, Can somebody guide me through what exactly is the problem and what can be the possible solutions.

Comment: I'm also facing same issue. Have you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The question marks cannot be turned back into Emoji.

The table/column must be declared `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.  (And then reload the characters.)

Also, you must have `SET NAMES utf8mb4` or `set_charset('utf8mb4'), or the equivalent, in your application code.

The link about Persian may not have been relevant, and did fail to show a need for utf8mb4.  (utf8 is adequate for Persian.)